# Excel VBA Macro Sub or Function not defined

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, macros, vba

I used the macro recorder to generate a macro in Excel 2007.  When I try to the run the macro, it tells me:

[image: Compile error: Sub or Function not defined]

When I click `Ok` the definition of the macro gets highlighted.

[image]

I'm really confused about why VBA would throw this error.  I just defined it!  Do you have any ideas what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 1st - check if there's no [missing reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507191/vba-cant-find-project-or-library-for-standard-vba-functions) in the VBA project.
- 2nd - It seems it needs the Solver Addin. Ensure it's checked in Excel Addins.

Comment: I'll check this out.  I didn't think about references.  Hopefully that is it.  Thanks.

Comment: You were right.  I didn't add Solver to the references for the project.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is pretty late (I'm a new arrival to SuperUser).
You need to go to VBA editor screen, choose References... from the Tools menu, find Solver and check the box to allow VBA to use Solver references in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I copied my code and created another module.  Right clicking Module1 in the Project Tree, I used the "Module1 properties" to change the name of the module to 'Day_Muster' (the name of my sub), but left the name Module1 alone (huh?).

Now when I hit alt-f8 in Outlook, I get the option to run 'Day_Muster'.  I click an everything is good!

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Do you know _what_ this does when you do it?